# windows form components preventing building project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Working on a Windows form in VB.Net, with a local git repository set up through Visual Studios 2017.

I added a second form, and found my project unable to build debug builds anymore, and after some testing, managed to isolate this as happening only when going beyond a certain number of components between the two forms. In total I have 12 components between the two forms. If I add any other components to either form it throws an error, but code changes will not cause any issues. The exact error is:

> Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\WindowsApp1.exe" to "bin\Debug\WindowsApp1.exe". Access to the path 'obj\Debug\WindowsApp1.exe' is denied.

Searching around for that error led me to believe that it was a git/team services error, but none of the typical causes and solutions seemed applicable. The solutions were either already in place or failed to solve the issue. The lack of relation between the error and apparent cause has me completely stumped.

Comment: There are only ever two reasons for this error.  One is that your program is still running but does not have a UI anymore.  Use Task Manager to check that.  The other is that your anti-malware is unhappy about an executable file appearing from seemingly no-where.  The larger it is the longer it is going to be unhappy.  Disable it to see if that changes anything.  Avast is especially notable, if you use it then get rid of it as soon as possible.

Comment: The anti-malware has been quarantining the files. Unfortunately it will be a while until I can disable it on this computer, but I think it's safe to say that was the cause. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your Application is still running in the backend. Please check in Taskmanager. if you find it there, kill it otherwise just restart your computer